# Masking cameras for Voronoi splitscreen

Tags: unity, shaders, rendering, camera

I would like to mask a camera to only render to a certain (non-square) region of the screen, to be used as an overlay, for splitscreen, or any other application.

The goal is obviously to prevent any unnecessary rendering from that camera, so I specified performance, but I'm also happy to hear the easiest to implement option as well.

What I'm considering so far:

1. Stencil shader on a mesh in front of the camera - but my understanding is that doing so would require modifying all shaders on world objects, which isn't ideal. Is there an easier way I'm missing?
2. Transparent mesh with a cutout - I could cut out a hole in a mesh and the solid part would block rendering of objects behind it, but I'm not sure how to make that part be transparent so other things can render

I'm using Unity 2019 LTS and the built-in render pipeline

I feel like there must be a simple answer I'm missing but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about the shape of this camera view, what it represents, and what's rendered around/outside it? There may be easier or more complicated options depending on those specifics.

Comment: Sure, it's for a voronoi splitscreen system. So multiple cameras would be rendering to their own screen regions, the shape of which could change moment to moment. I could render one camera as fullscreen and the others on top of it, or all could be masked. Does that help?

Comment: I don't think that putting something like a transparent mesh with a cutout in front of the camera as a sort of mask will actually cull anything behind the mesh; in other words, the engine would still render everything and simply draw the mask over the other rendered graphics. There would be no performance savings. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

Comment: What render pipeline are you using?

Comment: @Kevin The built in render pipeline in 2019 LTS, sorry I forgot mention it!

Comment: @Kevin I'm confused, that link says occlusion culling prevents drawing of objects that are occluded, which is exactly what I'm talking about? Since the occluded area would be most of the world, there should be a considerable performance impact. The question is just how to get it to work and then discard the pixels of the blocking object. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Please read that page, and related pages, in the manual thoroughly. Occlusion culling relies on data baked into the scene. Only stationary objects marked as "occluder static" will be considered as occluders. A mask attached to your camera cannot be a static occluder because it must move when the camera moves.

Comment: Although it might seem reasonable that the engine would automatically skip rendering any pixel that is obscured by any other opaque pixel, in reality this is not how game engines and GPUs work. I am not an expert in GPU architecture, but my understanding is that the highly parallelized nature of GPU rendering, combined with optimizations like batching, make occlusion culling very difficult. Without baked occlusion data, taking the time to figure out which objects are obscured and don't need to be rendered would actually slow down rendering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122435/discussion-between-kevin-and-appleguysnake).